# How is this move illegal?

Tags: rules, check, illegal-move

I'm black and it's my turn. I'm playing in the Arena chess player against Stockfish.
This is my current board:

```
[fen ""]
[startply "31"]

1. e4 d5 2. exd5 e6 3. dxe6 fxe6 4. Nf3 Nf6 5. Bc4 c6 6. O-O Bc5 7. d4 Bb6 8. Re1 O-O 9. Nc3 Nbd7 10. Ng5 Ne5 11. dxe5 Qxd1 12. Nxd1 Ng4 13. Nxe6 Bxf2+ 14. Nxf2 b5 15. Bb3 Nxf2 16. Nc7+
```

I want to play **Rb8**:

```
1rb2rk1/p1N3pp/2p5/1p2P3/8/1B6/PPP2nPP/R1B1R1K1 w - - 2 17
```

but I keep getting errors telling me that's illegal.

**HOW IS THIS ILLEGAL??**

Comment: You are in check and have to resolve that first.

Comment: Oh cripes. Yeah my bad. Thanks

Comment: For future reference, notice in that notation, after Nc7, there is a plus sign. That plus sign is chess notation for "check".

Comment: By the way, just because it is obvious to experienced players, that does not mean it is obvious to true novices, and thus, please keep your downvotes to yourself. It is not a bad question just because you think it is easy.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out I was in check:

[image]